# JsonUtility.ToJson in C# - possible error in utility

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine

I am trying to send non-sensitive user data over https using json format. I am using  JsonUtility.ToJson to convert an C# object into json. I start with a certain C# object, and first cast into another C# object, to remove some unwanted sensitive info. My issue is that JsonUtility seems not to use the casted object structure, and instead uses the original uncasted object structure.

If I have classes like:

```
Class A {
string name;
}

Class B: A {
string password;
}
```

Then, I say:

```
var myInstanceB = new B();
myInstanceB.name = "Fred";
myInstanceB.password = "1234";
```

Then,

```
A myInstanceA = (A)myInstanceB;
```

If I convert to json:

```
string httpBody = JsonUtility.ToJson(myInstanceA);
```

Unfortunately, I get that httpBody contains:

```
{"name":"Fred", "password":"1234"}
```

instead of:

```
{"name":"Fred"}
```

By casting to A, I expect the password to disappear.

Clearly, I can create a new object of class A, and individually assign the fields I need from B, but it seems unnecessary.

Thoughts?

Comment: `string ToJson(object obj)` takes an `object`, and is not generic, so it uses the runtime type of the object.  Casting doesn't change the runtime type.

Comment: Thanks. I don't see why the utility can't use the input type though.

Comment: Because the input type is `object`, and the runtime type is `B`.  Exercise: make a method that takes an argument of type `object`, and write some code in that method to get the objects actual type.  Even if you cast that object to `A` before passing it in, you will get `B` by using `obj.GetType()`.  You can't use the input type of `A` via casting because the method isn't generic; that information isn't retained.

Comment: okay. Just thought the JSONUtility could somehow be modified to enable desired function.